# Could not connect to Application Insights

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to create a new web application on Visual Studio Professional 2013. I found a message that "Your login has expired", I tried to sign in using my account but then I got the error message below. What does this mean? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the https://portal.azure.com/ and make sure that you have a subscription there. Though you can use Application Insights for free you need to have active Azure subscription. [Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-get-started/#get-started) you can read more about setting up application insights.